# OpenCV cv2.imwrite() is not working in loop to save images in folder

Tags: python, opencv

I am recognising faces from the webcam and I have datasets of some images.
when I am trying to save an image with the static name it saves that image but when I try to save images in the loop then it is not saving.

folder directory

1. imagesAttendance[Folder]
2. imageResult[Folder]
3. start.py

end folder directory

start.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image
# from PIL import ImageGrab
 
path = 'ImagesAttendance'
saveResults = 'ImageResult'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNames)
 
def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList
 
def markAttendance(name, img):
    with open('Attendance.csv','r+') as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()
        nameList = []
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])
        
        now = datetime.now()
        dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString}')
        ## saving image into database
        im = Image.fromarray(img)
        datee = str(now)
        cv2.imwrite('ImageResult/Image'+'anyname'+'.jpg', img)### this is working
        # cv2.imwrite('ImageResult/Image'+datee+'.jpg', img)### this is not working
    
 
#### FOR CAPTURING SCREEN RATHER THAN WEBCAM
# def captureScreen(bbox=(300,300,690+300,530+300)):
#     capScr = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox))
#     capScr = cv2.cvtColor(capScr, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
#     return capScr
 
encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print('Encoding Complete')
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    #img = captureScreen()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.25,0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
 
    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS,facesCurFrame)
    
    for encodeFace,faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame,facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
        #print(faceDis)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
 
        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
            #print(name)
            y1,x2,y2,x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4,x2*4,y2*4,x1*4
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y2-35),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img,name,(x1+6,y2-6),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(255,255,255),2)
            markAttendance(name, img)

            
            
    cv2.imshow('Webcam',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

working saveMatch() function

```
def markAttendance(name, img):
    with open('Attendance.csv','r+') as f:
        ...
        cv2.imwrite('ImageResult/Image'+'anyname'+'.jpg', img)### this is working
```

not working saveMatch() function

```
def markAttendance(name, img):
    with open('Attendance.csv','r+') as f:
        ...
                cv2.imwrite('ImageResult/Image'+datee+'.jpg', img)### this is not working
```

I want to save every detected images in ImageResult directory.

Comment: what is `datee`. I'm asking for the specific values it can assume. those strings probably contain characters that are **invalid** as file names.

Comment: Print 'ImageResult/Image'+datee+'.jpg' and check whether the filename and path makes sense (legal filename etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important note:**

In Macbook and Linux your saveMatch() function will work with the datee because the operation systems allow you to save files with characters as `:` for example.

**The Problem:**

In Windows, `:` is invalid character for a file name.

You are trying to save files with invaild characters in Windows, you can see in the following code what you get in using the function str(datetime.now())

```
date = datetime.now()
print(str(date))
>>>>> 2021-09-24 00:23:29.720260
```

you can read more about the [Comparison of filename limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) in the link.

**The Solution:**

you can fix it using the next method:

```
def markAttendance(name, img):
    with open('Attendance.csv','r+') as f:
        ...
        cv2.imwrite('ImageResult/Image'+str(datee.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'))'+'.jpg, img)
```

you can find more information about the strftime() function of the datetime package [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp).